# dotnet core - docker compose running but is not showing in the browser

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core

I have set Up docker with dotnet core 2.2 and when I use docker-compose up, it works and says that it is listening on port 8080 but I cannot see any output in the browser or from calling an api. here is my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.0'

services:
   db:
     image: mysql:latest
     environment:
       MYSQL_DATABASE: test
       MYSQL_USER: root
       MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: "true" 
     volumes:
       - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
       - _MySQL_Init_Script:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
     restart: always
   onlinesm.logs:
     image: test
     build: 
       context:  .
     ports:
       - "8080:80"
volumes:
  dbdata: {}
  _MySQL_Init_Script : {}
```

Comment: I sounds like your program is listening on port 8080. Then I think you need to reverse your ports specification to `80:8080`. The latter number is the port number inside the container and the first one is the port number on the container machine.

Comment: port 808 was a typo it is 8080

Comment: thanks it solved my problem